# jQuery Scroll function : Scroll Top and Window Height 1px discrepancy in value

Tags: jquery

This a function for infinate scroll. Sometimes it works, sometime the log output calucates a difference of 1 between the `$(window).scrollTop(),` and `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

What am I missing? Thanks

```
   $window.scroll(function() {  
     var position     = $(window).scrollTop(),
     docHeight    = $(document).height(),
     windowHeight = $(window).height(),
     bottom =  docHeight - windowHeight;

     console.log(position);
     console.log(bottom);

     if(position == bottom ) { 
       console.log('ajax'); 
       load_posts();  
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the browser sometimes adds its own stylesheet as well. That may be the cause of your issue. Try using [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). It resets all the browser default css.

And its always a good practice to trigger infinite scroll from around 50px of the bottom. You dont wanna have the user to scroll to "the very end" to show next content.

Comment: Thanks for 50px tip, that gets my feature working. However I'm still confused as to what is causing the problem- for instance, I imagined the javascript to be measuring the what the browser has `rendered` regardless of what style's are are applied. Your suggestion for a css reset doesn't sound wrong per say, I'd just like to understand better exactly what the javascript is taking it's measurements from.

Comment: every browser has its own default stylesheet called the user agent stylesheet which has default margin, padding etc. for the browser. This might be causing inconsistencies for the js while calculating. There is a nice list of css2 defaults given here http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm

Comment: cool, I guess I just have to read the methods I'm using to really understand what's going on, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.